# In VSCode, is it possible to apply eslinter formatting rules to just a block of code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I was able to figure out how to apply eslinter formatting rules to an entire file. However, I'd like to be able to apply it to just a part of the file (selected block of code).

I currently have Atom configured to do this (using Beautify package with ESLint Fixer as the Default Beautifier for Javascript). This allows me to select a block of code and run Beautify on it.

I'd like to move over to VSCode but really need this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a direct way to do it. A workaround:

- Put `/* eslint-disable */` at the top of the file. Then, before the block you want to lint, put `/* eslint-enable */` and after the block `/* eslint-disable */`.